# Page becoming temporarily non responsive when making ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Scenrio: I have a web app where users can vote on things, and everything gets loaded with ajax when they progress to the next vote. The user can also click on a previous vote and the details of the vote get loaded into the page with ajax. The issue I'm having is that when the user clicks through previous votes the page eventually freezes momentarily. This happens around the 7/8th click. Upon the first few clicks all of the new information gets loaded into the dom super quick, and everything is all good. When the page does freeze it becomes unfrozen after 20-25 seconds.

This is the js func that handles the clicks, and then I use a js.erb file to load the new information into the dom:

```
$('.vote.complete').click(function()
{
    whence = "toCompleted";
    vote_id = $(this).data('vote_id');
    cid = $(this).data('campaign_id');

    c_title = $('#outfitPair'+cid).data('campaign_title');
    u_id = $('#outfitPair'+cid).data('other_id');

    //_gaq = window._gaq;

  //if(_gaq != undefined){
   // _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPreviousVote', c_title, u_id]);
  //}

    $('#outfitPair'+cid).find('.button.vote').removeClass('to-vote');
    $(this).addClass('to-vote');

    $.get('/campaigns/new_pair?whence='+whence+'&vote_id='+vote_id)

return false;
});
```

The js.erb file is quite a bit to look through. I more or less looking for suggestions of possible causes that I can investigate though, I don't expect any exact answers given this little informations.

EDIT: I believe I've found a lead on the problem. It looks like each time you click on an old vote the # of ajax calls it makes grows by a factor of two, when it should only be making one.

http://i.imgur.com/QnvaaBD.png

Comment: Which browsers (with specific versions) does this happen in?

Comment: Do you have a callback function in there? It may not help load the content into the DOM faster after so many clicks, but it may help the page from being frozen. You could also 'unbind' the click until the AJAX has completely finished doing its thing. It's possible that you're queuing up the AJAX calls and after 7/8 clicks, the page freezes until all the communication is done.

Comment: Updated my question with what I believe to be the source of the problem.

Comment: How much data are you talking about? Is it possible that by the 7th call there's just way too much data for the browser to handle and it's causing memory issues?

Comment: @Jack, it should only be loading two images, and then some some text.

Comment: @xxyyxx Is the click event bound in an ajax callback?

Comment: Is turbolinks enabled?

Comment: why are you returning false at the end? There's no semi-colon after the $.get statement

Comment: I'm returning false to prevent the default action of clicking on an anchor tag with a "#" set as its href value. I've fixed the issue though. In my js.erb file I stated the click handler a second time thinking the old one was no longer bound when it still was. This ended up causing multiple ajax calls since the amount of click handlers would then double each time a vote was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. In my js.erb file I stated the click handler a second time thinking the old one was no longer bound when it still was. This ended up causing multiple ajax calls since the amount of click handlers would then double each time a vote was clicked. After removing the click handler from the callback everything now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, I would put in a conditional to prevent AJAX from making additional calls.

```
$('.vote.complete').click(function() {

if (!$(this).hasClass('loading')) {

     $(this).addClass('loading');

     $.get(url,function() {

          $(this).removeClass('loading');

     });

}

});
```